# Serial port in MVVMCross (.NET Standard Library)

Tags: serial-port, mvvmcross, .net-standard-2.0

I'm developing a WPF application for implementing a serial interface. I am implementing MVVM structure using **MVVMCross** framework. MVVMCross uses two projects in a solution, one is the core application that is a **.NET class library,** and the other is the WPF project.

Models and viewmodels exist in the .NET class library (.NET Standard 2.0). Serial port class does not exist in this standard but there is a System.IO.Ports nuget package to use serial ports.

My problem begins here, i am trying to use this nuget package but whenever i use serialport class, app throws an System.IO.FileNotFoundException. In the output it says (MvxBeginner.Core is the project name):

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in MvxBeginner.Core.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in MvxBeginner.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

I am not sure if this exception is related with .net standard or with MVVMCross. If anyone have any ideas i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i tried to solve this problem for a day. Problem is solved when i added the nuget package to WPF project as well. Before that i installed nuget package only to the core project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).